# Java String keep numeric characters only at the end of a String

Tags: java, string

what is the regular expression so I can keep only the LAST numbers at the END of a String?
For example

```
Test123 -> 123
T34est56 -> 56
123Test89 -> 89
```

Thanks

I tried

`str.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z\\s]", "");`  but this removes all the numbers of the String.
I also tried `str.replaceAll("\\d*$", "");` but this returns the following:

```
Test123 -> Test
 T34est56 -> T34est
 123Test89 -> 123Test
```

I want exactly the opposite.

Comment: You seem to be asking us to write the code for you. Please provide us with what you already tried so we can help you.

Comment: I tried the following:  str.replaceAll("\\d*$", "");
 but this keeps the String characters before the last numbers. I want to achieve the opposite

Comment: I also tried str.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z\\s]", "");   but this removes all the numbers

Comment: @IoannaKatsanou these are good attempts. Edit your question to include them there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting group of the last integers in line and then replacing string with that group seems to work:

```
    String str = "123Test89";
    String result = str.replaceAll(".*[^\\d](\\d+$)", "$1");
    System.out.println(result);
```

This outputs:

```
89
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replaceFirst()` to remove everything (`.*`) up to the last non-digit (`\\D`):

```
s = s.replaceFirst(".*\\D", "");
```

---

Complete example:

```
public class C {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String s = "T34est56";
        s = s.replaceFirst(".*\\D", "");

        System.out.println(s); // 56
    }
}
```

Comment: `replace and replaceFirst` woks the same here

Comment: but it's better to use replace if there are new lines `\n`

Answer (score 0):

I like to use the `Pattern` and `Matcher` API:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[1-9]*$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("Test123");
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group()); // 123
}
```

Comment: you code `123Test89` will give you `12389`, but should be `89`

Comment: Hi, did you run my code? `123Test89` gives `89` (as of version `11.0.9.1`)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex like this:

```
String result = str.replaceFirst(".*?(\\d+$)", "$1");
```

[**Try it online.**](https://tio.run/##PYzLDoIwEEX3fsVNwwJESXzGR9SFiTtXulMXFaqpViDtoDGGb8c2govJzNzHufEn796Se1XFihuDLZfppwXkxVnJGIY42fXMZIKHtfwdaZleDyfwwMWAS6ZrESQMrbkRmCEVLzTRD9tbo9cfsA7YfjC0z2jsbis5ZzJlZQ1DXYIWplCExZ8ZaZErHouN1IZ8FrVX/vGYhF7gQF6PBfMG8DYkHlFWUJRbFKnUbxghQ3cJFv7gdaNsuSmr6gs)

**Explanation:**

- `.*`: Any amount of leading characters
- `?`: Optionally. This makes sure the regex part after it (`(\\d+$)`) has priority over the `.*`. Without the `?`, every test case would only return the very last digit (i.e. `123Test89` would return `9` instead of `89`).
- `\\d+`: One or more digits
- `$`: At the very end of the string
- `(...)`: Captured in a capture group

Which is then replaced with:

- `$1`: The match of the first capture group (so the trailing digits)

To perhaps make it slightly more clear, you could add a leading `^` to the regex: `"^.*?(\\d+$)"`, although it's not really necessary because `.*` already matches every leading character.

Answer (score -3):

I think use /.*?(\d+)$/, it will work.